# How to map 6 bytes of raw data to long long type?

Tags: data-type, byte-order

I'm trying to solve some problems for a contest, and I have a problem with it. I have to implement a function that has 3 arguments like this:

```
void foo(unsigned char* A, unsigned char* B, unsigned char* C);
```

And what comes in, is 6 bytes of data. I have to convert these 6 bytes of data to integer data (maybe long long). The problem is, I don't know how to map the bytes in the right order.

I'm using an Arduino Uno board.

Please help me with it.

Comment: What is the right order of the six bytes? And how are they contained in the `char` arrays from the functions parameters?

Comment: @chrisl 0x123412341234 to {0x12,0x34,0x12,0x34,0x12,0x34}

Comment: I'm not quite sure, what exactly you want to do. As I understand you get 3 char arrays with each 2 bytes in the correct order as parameters into your function, and then you want to declare a `long long` and fill the bytes from the arrays into this variable. Is this correct?

Comment: @chrisl nope. each of the parameters inputs 6 byte of data. and I want to convert it like what I said/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use a `union` data type and get full control of the mapping. The issue of data representation and endian is now under your control:

```
uint64_t foo(uint8_t* A, uint8_t* B, uint8_t* C)
{
  union {
    uint64_t X;
    struct {
      uint8_t A[2];
      uint8_t B[2];
      uint8_t C[2];
      uint8_t D[2];
    };
  } map;
#if defined(MSB_ORDER)
  for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < 2; i++, j--) {
    map.A[i] = 0;
    map.B[i] = C[j];
    map.C[i] = B[j];
    map.D[i] = A[j];
  }
#else
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    map.A[i] = A[i];
    map.B[i] = B[i];
    map.C[i] = C[i];
    map.D[i] = 0;
  }
#endif
  return map.X;
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  uint8_t a[] = { 0x12, 0x34 };
  uint8_t b[] = { 0x56, 0x78 };
  uint8_t c[] = { 0x9a, 0xbc };
  uint64_t res = foo(a, b, c);
  Serial.print((uint32_t) (res >> 32), HEX);
  Serial.print((uint32_t) res, HEX);
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
uint64_t foo(uint8_t* A, uint8_t* B, uint8_t* C)
{
    uint64_t aux = 0;
    aux = A[0];
    aux <<= 8;
    aux |= A[1];
    aux <<= 8;
    aux |= B[0];
    aux <<= 8;
    aux |= B[1];
    aux <<= 8;
    aux |= C[0];
    aux <<= 8;
    aux |= C[1];
    return aux;
}
```

following sample code:

```
  uint8_t a[] = { 0x12, 0x34 };
  uint8_t b[] = { 0x56, 0x78 };
  uint8_t c[] = { 0x9a, 0xbc };

  uint64_t result = foo(a, b, c);

  std::cout << std::hex << result;
```

returns `123456789abc`, try [the code here](https://onlinegdb.com/S15ZvIfmQ), excluding the std::out part, the same code will run on arduino without any problem

Answer (score 0):

When passing data to functions you do this...

```
foo(a,b,c);
```

You then extract the variables or data passed to the function like..

```
void foo(unsigned char* A, unsigned char* B, unsigned char* C) {
    A = whatever;
    B = whatever;
    C = whatever;
}
```

Comment: wow. I'm not that noob ;;
I wanna map the raw 6 byte data to "long long" type variable. 
memcpy won't work as I want, cause of the endian rules..

Comment: Well your function was written wrong. So is each VAR or CHAR 2 bytes then?